# Is there a way to search for contacts with special characters in their name?

Tags: contacts

I have a Pixel 3. Some of my contacts have special characters in their name, e.g. "&". When I search for these contacts nothing comes up (nothing from my contacts, it will display some results, as far as I can tell they are results from the local caller ID lists).

Comment: Try different apps. Or develop a small one just for search purpose. It's simple.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion for a different contact app?